# Bash: Split stdout from multiple concurrent commands into columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am running multiple commands in a bash script using single ampersands like so:

```
commandA & commandB & commandC
```

They each have their own `stdout` output but they are all mixed together and flood the console in an incoherent mess.

I'm wondering if there is an easy way to pipe their outputs into their own columns... using the `column` command or something similar. ie. something like:

```
commandA | column -1 & commandB | column -2 & commandC | column -3
```

New to this kind of thing, but from initial digging it seems something like **[pr](http://man.cx/pr)** might be the ticket? or the `column` command...?

Comment: This may be better on the [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) Stackexchange site.

Comment: hmmmm, thanks... I didn't know that existed. Can I have the same question open on both sites? It's hard to know which site to use, since SO has a lot of bash users/scripters as well.

Comment: Would you be able to put them in temp files ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regrettably answering my own question.

None of the supplied solutions were exactly what I was looking for. So I developed my own command line utility: **[multiview](https://github.com/arjunmehta/node-multiview)**. Maybe others will benefit?

It works by piping processes' stdout/stderr to a command interface and then by launching a "viewer" to see their outputs in columns:

```
fooProcess | multiview -s & \
barProcess | multiview -s & \
bazProcess | multiview -s & \
multiview
```

This will display a neatly organized column view of their outputs. You can name each process as well by adding a string after the `-s` flag:

```
fooProcess | multiview -s "foo" & \
barProcess | multiview -s "bar" & \
bazProcess | multiview -s "baz" & \
multiview
```

There are a few other options, but thats the gist of it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

[`pr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pr) is a solution, but not a perfect one. Consider this, which uses [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) (`<(command)` syntax):

```
pr -m -t <(while true; do echo 12; sleep 1; done) \
         <(while true; do echo 34; sleep 2; done)
```

This produces a marching column of the following:

```
12                                  34
12                                  34
12                                  34
12                                  34
```

Though this trivially provides the output you want, the columns do not advance individually—they advance together when all files have provided the same output. This is tricky, because in theory the first column should produce twice as much output as the second one.

You may want to investigate invoking [`tmux`](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) or [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) in a tiled mode to allow the columns to scroll separately. A terminal multiplexer will provide the necessary machinery to buffer output and scroll it independently, which is important when showing output side-by-side without allowing excessive output from commandB to scroll commandA and commandC off-screen. Remember that scrolling each column separately will require a lot of screen redrawing, and the only way to avoid screen redraws is to have all three columns produce output simultaneously.

As a last-ditch solution, consider [piping each output to a command that indents each column by a different number of characters](https://serverfault.com/a/72814):

```
this is something that commandA outputs and is
    and here is something that commandB outputs
interleaved with the other output, but visually
you might have an easier time distinguishing one
        here is something that commandC outputs
    which is also interleaved with the others
from the other
```

Comment: Hmmmm, I think none of these are perfect. pr doesn't quite do the trick for my output, it's hard to find the right column size and alignment seems off. Number of processes may vary too. I'm trying to view multiple console.logs from multiple processes in one place. Like you say, with pr the output needs to be synchronized so the output ends up looking quite weird. But it is efficient. I actually started writing my own utility in node that has the interface I want and displays in independent columns. But I see what you mean about redrawing the entire screen. It's not efficient!!

Comment: Thank you for your great answer though! Your last point about indenting is actually really efficient, but would be too messy for multiple processes with a lot of output. I also feel like a terminal multiplexer might actually be the right answer, but I'm almost wondering if it's easier to write my own utility than to figure out and rely on a utility like screen or tmux which may or may not exist on a user's system.

Answer (score 2):

Script print out three vertical rows and a timer each row containing the output from a single script.
Comment on anything you dont understand and ill add answers to my answer as needed

Hope this helps :)

```
#!/bin/bash
#Script by jidder

count=0
Elapsed=0
control_c()
{
    tput rmcup
    rm tail.tmp
    rm tail2.tmp
    rm tail3.tmp
    stty sane
}


Draw()
{
       tput clear
       echo "SCRIPT 1                                                                                                                     Elapsed time =$Elapsed seconds"
        echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        tail -n10 tail.tmp
        tput cup 25 0

        echo "Script 2                                                                                                                                                   "
        echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        tail -n10 tail2.tmp
        tput cup 50 0

        echo "Script 3                                                                                                                                                   "
        echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        tail -n10 tail3.tmp
}


Timer()
{
        if [[ $count -eq 10  ]]; then
                Draw
                ((Elapsed = Elapsed + 1))
                count=0
        fi


}
main()
{
    stty -icanon time 0 min 0
    tput smcup
    Draw
    count=0
    keypress=''
    MYSCRIPT1.sh > tail.tmp &
    MYSCRIPT2.sh > tail2.tmp &
    MYSCRIPT3.sh > tail3.tmp &

    while [ "$keypress" != "q" ]; do
            sleep 0.1
            read keypress
            (( count = count + 2 ))
            Timer
    done

    stty sane
    tput rmcup
    rm tail.tmp
    rm tail2.tmp
    rm tail3.tmp
    echo "Thanks for using this script."
    exit 0
}

main

trap control_c SIGINT
```

Comment: Wowwww. This is amazing! I hope you didn't write it just for this question though. I can definitely make temp files. I decided to build my own similar thing using node and a unix socket. Thanks for such a thorough answer!